# Set the Version of a Secret When Setting the Secret in Azure KeyVault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

It doesn't seem like it's possible currently to set the version of an Azure Key Vault secret when uploading the secret. I'm using SetSecretAsync. Am I missing something? Even when attempting the operation from the Azure Portal, you aren't given the opportunity to set the version, nor is there a way to back up or restore a secret.

It seems like this is intentional (given the seeming lack of methods to do it), but consider the background of why I'm doing this. We're concerned with a secret being deleted by mistake or even the vault itself being deleted by mistake. As we're using the secrets for encryption/decryption purposes, if the secrets or vault were to be deleted, we would have an issue... So we are planning to back up the secrets to blob storage in the event we do need to restore them. With keys in the vault, a simple way to do this type of operation is available, but it doesn't seem secrets were given this same treatment unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, just look at the rest call to do that, there's no option for that.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/setsecret

Answer (score 0):

Based on operations performed directly from the portal while delete secret seems to be permanent, update (New Version option in portal, there is no update) on the other hand is merely adding a new version where as version cannot be explicitly mentioned but internally managed by KeyVault. Even in API Reference you can get all the versions of a single secret (see below). So update REST API might as well be just setting a new version and not actually overwriting. So as long as UPDATE is used and instead of delete probably set expiry through update we are covered.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecretversions